# Javascript doesn't detect the ID of an element in the HTML document. Returns 'Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a div element in HTML submit a form using Javascript, however after writing the function and defining the id of the element, the console in the browser outputs 'Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined'.

```
<form action="recipe.html" id="recipeForm" name="chicken_recipe"> 
   <input type='hidden' name='recipename' value='Chicken Pot Pie'>
        <section class="col-4 popOut row-m-b" >
           <div class="card" style="max-width: 367px;" onclick="submitForm()">
               <img src="images/half-price-burgers.jpg" class="card-img-top absolute" alt="Card Image"/>
                   <div class="card-block" style="transform: scale(1);">
                     <h4 class="card-title" style="transform: scale(1);">Sample Title</h4>
                     <p class="card-text" style="transform: scale(1);">Sample Text Description Lorem Ipsum Do</p>
                   </div>
           </div>
        </section>
</form>
```

In getRecipe.js, this is the following code:

```
function submitForm() {
document.getElementById('recipeForm').submit();
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is so, as I am sure the naming conventions are correct. Why is the object null when I have assigned an id to it?

I'm not sure if it's worth mentioning, but plainly running the code 'getElementById(recipeForm)' returns null. I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is the pastebin file with my HTML code:
https://pastebin.com/dcUngCCf

Here's what's inside the getRecipe.js file: 
https://pastebin.com/RrgAyLyh

Comment: It should work. Also are you sure about the error? DOM functions return null and not undefined. Are you saving this in some variable and then using it?

Comment: Make sure that the HTML is rendered before triggering the `submitForm()` function.

Comment: would it be possible for you to recreate the problem with [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a snippet within your question? If not then maybe provide a [**Paste Bin**](https://pastebin.com/) since the source code you have given seems to be working just fine and I cannot seem to recreate the problem you are having. Thank you.

Comment: @Rajesh I have looked at the error again and it's returning null this time. Guess the undefined was something else.

Comment: Thank you for the pastebin but your **`submitForm()`** function isn't even in the pastebin so I can only assume it's in `getRecipe.js` which I can't read/view/see to debug.

Comment: Yup. Sorry about that, I pasted what was inside the getRecipe.js file to another pastebin file.

Answer (score -4):

### Javascript

```
function submitForm() {
    document.getElementById('recipeForm').submit();
}
```

**OR**

take `name` attribute of form tag.

HTML

```
<form action="recipe.html" id="recipeForm" name="chicken_recipe"> 
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function submitForm() {
    document.chicken_recipe.submit();
}
```

### jQuery

You can directly call `submit()` on element id using jQuery.

```js
function submitForm() {
$('#recipeForm').submit();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="recipe.html" id="recipeForm" name="chicken_recipe"> 
   <input type='hidden' name='recipename' value='Chicken Pot Pie'>
        <section class="col-4 popOut row-m-b" >
           <div class="card" style="max-width: 367px;" onclick="submitForm()">
               <img src="images/half-price-burgers.jpg" class="card-img-top absolute" alt="Card Image"/>
                   <div class="card-block" style="transform: scale(1);">
                     <h4 class="card-title" style="transform: scale(1);">Sample Title</h4>
                     <p class="card-text" style="transform: scale(1);">Sample Text Description Lorem Ipsum Do</p>
                   </div>
           </div>
        </section>
</form>
```

Comment: jQuery is not tagged in question. Also what is the problem in OP's coffee that your answer fixes?

Comment: Once again, another `jQuery` solution for a question with no `jQuery` tag.

Comment: @NewToJS Included both ways Javascript and jQuery. Thanks.

Answer (score -5):

You can try below code.

```
function submitForm() {
document.getElementById('recipeForm')[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` returns an Element or `null`, never an array.